# имплементация интерфейса

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

**Есть один интерфейс который содержит один virtual метод(Hello), а этот интерфейс имплементируется в class B. Сделал override этого метода и хочу сделать так чтобы после имплементаций этого интерфейса вызывался тот метод которому сделал override, как это сделать ?**

```
public interface IMethods
{
    string Hello();
}

public class B : IMethods
{
   public virtual string Hello()
   {
      return "Hello from Russia";
   }
}

public class C : IMethods
{
   public virtual string Hello()
   {
      return "Hello from Italy";
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы не сможете вызвать overriden метод за пределами класса, даже если попробуете сделать приведение типов к классу B. В этом и есть смысл virtual функций. Однако вы можете объявить вашу функцию не virtual, а new, тогда у вас останется доступ к функции базового класса.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var c = new C();
        Console.Write((c as B).Hello());
    }
}

public interface IMethods
{
    string Hello();
}

public class B : IMethods
{
    public virtual string Hello()
    {
        return "Hello from Russia";
    }
}

public class C : B
{
    public new string Hello()
    {
        return "Hello from Italy";
    }
}
```